# use arima to prediction timeseries

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting, arima

I try to use ARIMA to predict time series.

```
ts <- c(283.678,278.158,273.345,269.773,265.863,265.673,262.977,272.557,267.628,270.106,276.346,292.736,310.649,320.550,332.954,350.313,361.524,367.406,369.442,372.043,365.030,375.210,371.006,364.991,359.975,365.849,373.687,368.167,368.281,366.982,365.752,366.844,356.526,356.667,354.937,352.461,353.742,357.139,362.981,384.613,405.519,400.974,388.696,374.536,348.781,324.664,307.051,297.943)
ar <- arima(ts)
ps <- predict(ar, 48)
plot(c(ts, ps$pred), type="l")
```

Why did this code predict plain line instead of some similiar curve?

[image]

Comment: Study the parameter `xreg` from the arguments of `arima`

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot to add the variable `order` in `arima()`, hence fitted an `ARIMA(0,0,0)` model, which is just a constant intercept term.

If you want to automatically fit an ARIMA model of appropriate order (selected by AIC, AICc or BIC), you can use `auto.arima()` from the `forecast` package:

```
library(forecast)
ar <- auto.arima(ts)
ps <- predict(ar, 10)
ps
# $pred
# Time Series:
# Start = 49 
# End = 58 
# Frequency = 1 
# [1] 291.7978 287.6517 284.8543 282.9668 281.6934 280.8342 280.2545 279.8634 279.5995 279.4214
```

Comment: With auto.arima it also predict a plain line but below

Comment: In the code above you can see that it is _not_ a constant value. Due to the high AR value, the process will quickly converge to its unconditional mean (which is about 279). You can't expect better results from a 48-step ahead prediction.